# fscanf returns 3 instead of -1 (EOF) at the end of the file

Tags: c, scanf, eof

So there's a file I'm using fscanf() in. I've set a condition in my code that when (fscanf(...) == EOF, the program needs to break out of the function I'm currently in. The thing is, this condition is never satisfied in any of the cases where there's no more lines of text in the file. EOF is always -1, whereas fscanf(...) returns 4 each time there's a line of code, and 3 when there's nothing left for it to search through (instead of -1). If I add a line of code similar to the other ones, I will simply get one more instance of fscanf() returning 4, and then again, it'll give me a 3.

What could possibly be the issue? Thank you in advance!

Sample text file content:

CHRISTOU GIORGOS,140,VAS. OLGAS 112

MALAKOU MALAKOS,150,DRAS. BAGAS 12

TSIKOU GIJRAN,140,JABS. DRALGAS 1

TSIKOU BIRBAN,140,JABS. DRALGAS 1

DELHDHMHTRIOU SPYROS,50,SPEED. BAGAS 62

FOX SIN,40,BAN. NINJA 1

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define M 100

typedef struct {
    char name[30];
    int apousies;
} studentT;

void readInput (FILE* infile, studentT students[], int *pApousies, int *pStudents);


int main()
{
    char inputfilename[30];
    FILE* infile;

    while (1) {
        printf("Input file name :");
        gets(inputfilename);

        infile  = fopen(inputfilename, "r");

        if (infile != NULL) break;
        printf("Cannot open input file %s. Try again.\n", inputfilename);
    }

    studentT students[M];
    int numberOfStudents = 0, numberOfApousies = 0;
    readInput(infile, students, &numberOfApousies, &numberOfStudents);
    fclose(infile);
    return 0;
}

void readInput (FILE* infile, studentT students[], int *pApousies, int *pStudents)
{
    int nscan, apousies, studcount, apouscount, line;
    char name[30], comments[68], termch;

    line = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        nscan = fscanf(infile, "%30[^,], %d, %68[^\n]%c", name, &apousies, comments, &termch);
       /* printf("onoma: %s apousies: %d sxolia: %s terma: %c\n", name, apousies, comments, termch);
        printf("%d\n", nscan);
        printf("%d\n", EOF);*/
        if (nscan == EOF) break; 
        line++;

        if (nscan != 4 || termch != '\n')
        {
            printf("Error in line %d. Program termination\n", line);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `(fscanf(...) == EOF` the program needs to break out of the function --> That is a weak test.  Better to test against the one desired return - perhaps like `(fscanf(...) != 4`.  Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Post definition of `studentT`.  The post is better, yet not complete enough to compile.

Comment: I wasn't sure as to which parts of the code were relevant to the question. I hope this helps. Thanks again.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing exactly how you are using `fscanf()`, particularly your actual format string

Comment: Note that your code is strange. You pass `pApousies` as a parameter to the function `readInput`, and don't use it.  The you declare a local variable `apousies` and use it in the call to fscanf.  Your test of `nscan == EOF` looks ok to me.

Comment: To reproduce the problem, it would have been better to form the text file from code that post it.  I suspect your true text file differs from the one here in some white-space way.

Comment: the function: `fscanf()`  like all the `scanf()` family of function, returns the number of successful conversion.  Except when no successful conversions and not characters left in file (not even a '\n') and it is trying to read past the end of file, then it returns EOF

Answer (score 4):

> fscanf returns 3 instead of -1 (EOF) at the end of the file

Because the last line lacks a `'\n'`.

---

OP's code "works" with the `"tmp.txt"` the below code makes.

`fscanf()` is hard to use right.  Easier to code and debug with `fgets()`.  Discussion follows.

---

`"%30[^,]"` allows too much for `char name[30]`.  Use `char name[30+1]` or `"%29[^,]"`

OP's approach can readily fail with seemingly minor parsing problems such as a missing `'\n'` on the last line.  After such a failure, recovery is extraordinary difficult with `fscanf()`

Debug: Importantly, the below print should not be attempted until code insures `nscan >= 4`

```
if (nscan >= 4) // add
  printf("onoma: %s apousies: %d sxolia: %s terma: %c\n", name, apousies,  comments, termch);
```

---

Instead, use `fgets()`.  With *line* orientated data, this really is the best first step.

`fscanf()` is challenging to use and cope with errors.  Far simpler to read a *line* with `fgets()` and then parse.

Using `" %n"` is a nice way to detect if *all* the line parsed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define M 100

typedef struct {
  char name[30];
  int apousies;
} studentT;

void readInput(FILE* infile, studentT students[], int *pApousies,
    int *pStudents) {
  (void) students;
  (void) pApousies;
  (void) pStudents;
  int line = 0;
  char buf[200];
  while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, infile)) {
    int apousies;
    char name[30], comments[68];
    int n = 0;

    line++;
    sscanf(buf, " %29[^,],%d , %67[^\n] %n", name, &apousies, comments, &n);
    if (n == 0 || buf[n]) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error in line %d <%s>. Program termination\n", line, buf);
      exit(1);
    }
    printf("Success %d <%s> %d <%s>\n", line, name, apousies, comments);
  }
}
```

Sample use

```
int main() {
  FILE *f = fopen("tmp.txt", "w");
  fputs("CHRISTOU GIORGOS,140,VAS. OLGAS 112\n"
      "MALAKOU MALAKOS,150,DRAS. BAGAS 12\n"
      "TSIKOU GIJRAN,140,JABS. DRALGAS 1\n"
      "TSIKOU BIRBAN,140,JABS. DRALGAS 1\n"
      "DELHDHMHTRIOU SPYROS,50,SPEED. BAGAS 62\n"
      "FOX SIN,40,BAN. NINJA 1\n", f);
  fclose(f);

  f = fopen("tmp.txt", "r");
  studentT st[M];
  readInput(f, st, NULL, NULL);
  fclose(f);
}
```

Output

```
Success 1 <CHRISTOU GIORGOS> 140 <VAS. OLGAS 112>
Success 2 <MALAKOU MALAKOS> 150 <DRAS. BAGAS 12>
Success 3 <TSIKOU GIJRAN> 140 <JABS. DRALGAS 1>
Success 4 <TSIKOU BIRBAN> 140 <JABS. DRALGAS 1>
Success 5 <DELHDHMHTRIOU SPYROS> 50 <SPEED. BAGAS 62>
Success 6 <FOX SIN> 40 <BAN. NINJA 1>
```